# Помогите с переносом regexp с js на golang?

Tags: javascript, node.js, регулярные-выражения, golang

имеется регулярное выражение, написанное на javascript:

```
/(?<=^|[^а-я])(([уyu]|[нзnz3][аa]|(хитро|не)?[вvwb][зz3]?[ыьъi]|[сsc][ьъ']|(и|[рpr][аa4])[зсzs]ъ?|([оo0][тбtb6]|[пp][оo0][дd9])[ьъ']?|(.\B)+?[оаеиeo])?-?([еёe][бb6](?!о[рй])|и[пб][ае][тц]).*?|([нn][иеаaie]|([дпdp]|[вv][еe3][рpr][тt])[оo0]|[рpr][аa][зсzc3]|[з3z]?[аa]|с(ме)?|[оo0]([тt]|дно)?|апч)?-?[хxh][уuy]([яйиеёюuie]|ли(?!ган)).*?|([вvw][зы3z]|(три|два|четыре)жды|(н|[сc][уuy][кk])[аa])?-?[бb6][лl]([яy](?!(х|ш[кн]|мб)[ауеыио]).*?|[еэe][дтdt][ь']?)|([рp][аa][сзc3z]|[знzn][аa]|[соsc]|[вv][ыi]?|[пp]([еe][рpr][еe]|[рrp][оиioеe]|[оo0][дd])|и[зс]ъ?|[аоao][тt])?[пpn][иеёieu][зz3][дd9].*?|([зz3][аa])?[пp][иеieu][дd][аоеaoe]?[рrp](ну.*?|[оаoa][мm]|([аa][сcs])?([иiu]([лl][иiu])?[нщктлtlsn]ь?)?|([оo](ч[еиei])?|[аa][сcs])?[кk]([оo]й)?|[юu][гg])[ауеыauyei]?|[мm][аa][нnh][дd]([ауеыayueiи]([лl]([иi][сзc3щ])?[ауеыauyei])?|[оo][йi]|[аоao][вvwb][оo](ш|sh)[ь']?([e]?[кk][ауеayue])?|юк(ов|[ауи])?)|[мm][уuy][дd6]([яyаиоaiuo0].*?|[еe]?[нhn]([ьюия'uiya]|ей))|мля([тд]ь)?|лять|([нз]а|по)х|м[ао]л[ао]фь([яию]|[её]й))(?=($|[^а-я]))/gm
```

Соответственно goLang его не примет из-за "?", что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: А есть пример данных? Что на входе и что должно получится на выходе?

Comment: матное слово, необходимо вывести true/false, чтобы понять что, сообщение нужно удалить

Comment: покажите код на go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Встроенная реализация `regexp` не поддерживает многие продвинутые фичи PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression). В вашем случае встроенный компилятор регулярных выражений ломается на самой первой look-ahead группе `(?<=...)`

Вам нужно использовать стороннюю библиотеку регулярных выражений, поддерживающую PCRE.

Я попробовал https://github.com/d4l3k/go-pcre
Ваше выражение скомпилировалось без проблем.

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    pcre "github.com/gijsbers/go-pcre"
)

func main() {
    testLine := "абракадабра"
    jsRe := `/(?<=^|[^а-я])(([уyu]|[нзnz3][аa]|(хитро|не)?[вvwb][зz3]?[ыьъi]|[сsc][ьъ']|(и|[рpr][аa4])[зсzs]ъ?|([оo0][тбtb6]|[пp][оo0][дd9])[ьъ']?|(.\B)+?[оаеиeo])?-?([еёe][бb6](?!о[рй])|и[пб][ае][тц]).*?|([нn][иеаaie]|([дпdp]|[вv][еe3][рpr][тt])[оo0]|[рpr][аa][зсzc3]|[з3z]?[аa]|с(ме)?|[оo0]([тt]|дно)?|апч)?-?[хxh][уuy]([яйиеёюuie]|ли(?!ган)).*?|([вvw][зы3z]|(три|два|четыре)жды|(н|[сc][уuy][кk])[аa])?-?[бb6][лl]([яy](?!(х|ш[кн]|мб)[ауеыио]).*?|[еэe][дтdt][ь']?)|([рp][аa][сзc3z]|[знzn][аa]|[соsc]|[вv][ыi]?|[пp]([еe][рpr][еe]|[рrp][оиioеe]|[оo0][дd])|и[зс]ъ?|[аоao][тt])?[пpn][иеёieu][зz3][дd9].*?|([зz3][аa])?[пp][иеieu][дd][аоеaoe]?[рrp](ну.*?|[оаoa][мm]|([аa][сcs])?([иiu]([лl][иiu])?[нщктлtlsn]ь?)?|([оo](ч[еиei])?|[аa][сcs])?[кk]([оo]й)?|[юu][гg])[ауеыauyei]?|[мm][аa][нnh][дd]([ауеыayueiи]([лl]([иi][сзc3щ])?[ауеыauyei])?|[оo][йi]|[аоao][вvwb][оo](ш|sh)[ь']?([e]?[кk][ауеayue])?|юк(ов|[ауи])?)|[мm][уuy][дd6]([яyаиоaiuo0].*?|[еe]?[нhn]([ьюия'uiya]|ей))|мля([тд]ь)?|лять|([нз]а|по)х|м[ао]л[ао]фь([яию]|[её]й))(?=($|[^а-я]))/gm`
    // jsRe := "(?<=бра)(ка)"
    goRe, err := pcre.Compile(jsRe, 0)
    if err != nil {
        println("Error:", err.Error())
        return
    }
    println("PCRE compile: No error")
    matcher := goRe.NewMatcher()
    matched := matcher.MatchString(testLine, 0)
    fmt.Printf("Tried line '%s': result %v\n", testLine, matched)
    if matched {
        index := matcher.Index()
        start := index[0]
        end := index[1]
        fmt.Printf("Match: '%s'\n", testLine[start:end])
        for g := 0; g <= matcher.Groups(); g++ {
            s := matcher.GroupString(g)
            println("Group #", g, ": ", s)
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Для проверки работоспособности раскомментируйте тестовое регулярное выражение `(?<=бра)(ка)`
Результат будет

```
PCRE compile: No error
Tried line 'абракадабра': result true
Match: 'ка'
Group # 0 :  ка
Group # 1 :  ка
```

Группа 0 - это всё регулярное выражение. Группа `(?<=бра)` игнорируется при подсчёте групп, так как lookahead. Остаётся только `ка`.

Другими словами, работает.